# Building a C# console app is editing an XML config file and crashes application on start up

Tags: c#, xml, dynamics-crm

I am writing a console application to work with Dynamics CRM. I have specified the XML configuration file for the application as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
  <configSections>
    <section name="microsoft.xrm.client" type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Configuration.CrmSection, Microsoft.Xrm.Client" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Xrm" connectionString="Server=XXXX://XXXXXXX:XXXX/XXXX; Domain=XXXXXXX; Username=XXXXXX; Password=XXXXXX" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <microsoft.xrm.client>
    <contexts>
      <add name="Xrm" type="Xrm.XrmServiceContext, Xrm" />
    </contexts>
  </microsoft.xrm.client>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ServiceBus" publicKeyToken="XXXXXXXX" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.5.0.0" newVersion="2.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

However upon building and running the console app, it did not like the `<startup>` tag at all and crashed, raising the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configur
ation system failed to initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsE
xception: Only one <configSections> element allowed per config file and if prese
nt must be the first child of the root <configuration> element. (C:\Users\admini
strator.XXXX\Desktop\XXXXX\XXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX
XXXXXX.exe.Config line 6)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignor
eLocal)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(Configurat
ionSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey
)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey
)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Intern
al.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Configuration.CrmConfigurationManager.CreateProvider(
)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmOrganizationServiceContext..ctor(String contextNam
e)
   at Xrm.XrmServiceContext..ctor(String contextName) in C:\Users\XXXXXX\
Desktop\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXX
XXXXXX\Xrm.cs:line 245616
   at XXXXXXXX.consoleApp.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\XXXXX
\XXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXX
XXXXX\XXXXX.cs:line 22
```

So from the error definition, I figured I'd remove the startup tag manually so that the `<configSections>` would be on top. Running it again worked (it grabbed the data I wanted from CRM). However after having done some further work and built the application again, the `<startup>` tag was automatically injected and therefore it crashed the app again. Is there a clean way to stop the `<startup>` tag from being added?

Comment: don't remove startup tag. Move it to the end and try?

Comment: What version of visual Studio?

Comment: Putting the `<startup>` tag in a different section will still cause to be removed and added on top again upon building the app

Comment: @IanKemp v14.0.24720.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by modifying the `App` config file that would be in the same directory as the `bin`, `obj` folders etc.

Putting the `<startup>` tag in the last part of the XML in this file will build the console app config in the same manner.